# In the Transformer, how do I get the Keys and the Values from the output of the top encoder (which go into Encoder-Decoder Attention)?

Tags: machine-learning, transformers, attention

I am trying to implement [Attention is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper in PyTorch without looking at any code.

**I'm struggling to understand how do I get the Keys and the Values from the output of the top encoder.** Do I learn 2 linear projections which take as input the output of the top encoder (which is a single matrix) and output the keys (or values) matrix? I don't quite understand it from the original paper, nor from [The Illustrated Transformer](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/). I understand how to get the Queries; they are obtained the same way as in the encoder self-attention layer: via a learned linear projection (linear layer).